# OpenMP in Visual Studio 2005 Standard

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2005, openmp

I have used OpenMP with gcc for writing parallel code. I am now using Visual C++ 2005 and am trying to figure out how to use OpenMP. There is a compiler option in the Properties->C/C++/Language menu but then it complains the library is missing. Is there a 3rd party implementation for OpenMP or am i just configuring Visual C++ incorrectly?

Comment: This also seems to apply to Visual Studio 2008 standard.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After some research I found out that the OpenMP libs and dlls are not included with Visual C++ 2005 or Visual C++ Express Edition 2008. But with a few workarounds you can get it working.

First you need to download the lib files from microsoft which can be found at the  [Windows SDK for Windows Server 2008 and .NET framework 3.5](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E6E1C3DF-A74F-4207-8586-711EBE331CDC&displaylang=en). After you download it you need to make sure that either vcomp.lib or vcompd.lib is being linked to your program.

Next you need to have the dll which can be found in the [Visual C++ Redistributable Packkage](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=9B2DA534-3E03-4391-8A4D-074B9F2BC1BF&displaylang=en). Then make sure that vcomp90.dll is somewhere in your path.

You also need to have the OpenMP compiler option enabled which can be found in the Properties->C/C++/Language menu of Visual C++.

After that you should be able to use OpenMP just fine.

Comment: It's also not included in the Standard versions as far as I can tell. Sounds like you need Professional or Team System versions. Here's a blog post that backs up what the above answer indicates.
http://kenny-tm.xanga.com/651048063/parallel-programming-using-openmp-with-visual-c-2008-express/

Comment: I know this is old but I was able to get openMP to work with visual c++ 2008 by simply installing the SDK linked above. Didn't need to do the other steps mentioned but they might work for other people.

Answer (score 6):

I think t works out of the box with VC 2005 but I am not sure if they are provided with all versions.

If you jsut attach the

```
/openmp
```

option you also have to include the open mp header

```
#include <omp.h>
```

This is important because this header will add the manifest to your application which
enables it to load the vcomp.dll from the correct system path. So it is normally no longer
allowed to copy vcomp.dll or other system dlls beneath your executable but you have to pimp the manifest of your application to load the dll from the correct location.
This is none automatically by the omp.h header.

So the minimum code if you do not want to modyfy your manifest on your own is:

```
#include <omp.h> // has to include this header to build the correct manifest to find vcom.dll or vcompd.dll

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  double sum;
#pragma omp parallel for
  for(int i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {

  }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was missing the include file (wasn't in the tutorial I was following...) A good reason to always show the includes in tutorials!

Answer (score 1):

You need to add:

```
/openmp
```

To your compiler options.

More information is available on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fw509c3b(VS.80).aspx)